# Google Cloud Account Deletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I really need your help in closing my google cloud account. The reason for this is because my company name has changed: From: Macventure.ca to Macventure.agency.

I haven't figured out how to delete this account. Technically I'm not sure if I signed up my google cloud account under a different email: marcia.turley@gmail.com. I am a newbie. Spent hours today trying to delete this account, figure out how to set up a new project and/or change the company info. I am using google cloud to setup Wordpress WP mail SMTP so that I can receive send emails to inbox.

My other gmail account (which I referred above) is marcia.turley@gmail.com

I appreciate your help.

Thanks so much!

Best wishes,
Marcia Turley

Answer (score 0):

**Please remove personal data such as personal email id from question.** F
Follow below steps to delete your google account.

1.Go to your Google Account.

2.On the left navigation Panel, click Data & personalization.

3.On the Download, delete, or make a plan for your data panel, click Delete a service or your account.

4.On the Delete your Google Account panel, click Delete your account.

Also for closing billing account check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#close_a_billing_account).

Comment: Thank you. This really helped! I was able to find out which google account that I need to make remove from the google cloud account. I did follow your instructions but when I got to step 3: download, delete or make a plan for my data panel, click delete a service or your account.. the only services linked to this account are YouTube and my personal email account. I just want to delete the organization and/or delete my email account: In Google Console so I can use the other gmail account instead.

Comment: @MarciaTurley below link will help you to delete account in Google console.     https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314

Comment: Thanks again Nikhil! Wow. It's day two... hopefully getting closer to finding a solution thanks to your help! Woo hoo.... Celebration when this happens.

Comment: Q: Delete or remove a user from your organization

Comment: I found a way better way to ask this question. Really had no clue about the links between Google Cloud, Organizations and Google Admin. Getting a better handle on that now though I think. Here's what I thought was a better way to ask this question. https://serverfault.com/questions/1067450/two-days-in-the-trenches-how-to-delete-google-cloud-organization-im-settin

Comment: The organization name is tied to the domain name. This cannot be changed. You can create a different G Suite or Cloud Identity account based upon another domain name that you own/control which will result in a new organization with a different name.

Therefore, there is no need to delete the organization. To delete an organization requires deleting the G Suite / Cloud Identity account.

The only items that you can change are who controls the organization and what billing account is linked to the organization.

Comment: You cannot move the organization. An organization stands at the top, everything else is under it. No account owns an organization. You can change the billing account and delete the old one. You can delete any projects under it. If you no longer want the organization name, remove the billing account and yourself as an IAM member - but remember you will not be able to reuse the same name or domain name

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Nikhil. You mentioned that the organization is tied to the domain name which makes sense. I just want to change the identity organization account in google cloud. At the time I created the organization in google cloud, I only owned the domain name for Macventure.ca  via my web hosting provider. I later bought the paid version of Gmail for my company. Question: What is the easiest way to establish the identity for Macventure.Agency account in google cloud? Sorry for all the questions. I'm still no clear about what the solution is.

Comment: Please do not answer with new questions. Please post a new question instead.