# Two days in the trenches.... How to delete google cloud organization? I'm setting up Gmail to Send WordPress Emails

Tags: smtp, wordpress, cloud, google, organizational-unit

How to delete google cloud organization?

Greetings from Nice, France,

I've got a question which I can't wait to hear what the solution is.... I'm setting up Gmail to Send WordPress Emails. I'm so **happy** you (my fine reader) might be able to help me.

Here's the big deal. I created a google cloud identity organization account (1st time using google cloud) using my web domain about 5 months ago. In the meantime, I changed my  organization name from macventure.ca TO **macventure.agency.** I therefore want to delete the *macventure.ca organization that linked to my google cloud identity.

PS I was able to update company name in Google ADMIN panel and was also able to delete macventure.ca with no difficulty. If only I could do the same in the Google console.

To make everything easier, I created this **short video** so you can see what the real problem is:

https://www.loom.com/share/fb92450300734072a06e6099d172b0e2

**PROBLEM**
I'm NOT ABLE to delete macventure.ca OR update it to macventure.agency in google console. I have tried now for two days without any breakthrough whatsoever. I'm in the process of setting up WordPress using the Gmail SMTP Server and therefore need to be able to create a new project. I'm really hoping you can help.

Looking forward to learning more about solution to this tricky challenge,
Marcia

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization